# Getting "invalid texture" depending on where I create the texture

Tags: c++, sdl-2

The texture doesn't appear on the screen and `SDL_RenderCopy` returns the error code "invalid texture". However, this will only happen if I load the surface in the constructor, not in the `Init` function.

It also doesn't happen if I don't destruct the texture with:

```
SDL_DestroyTexture(image_);
```

I use this to load the images (didn't do this part of the code):

```
SDL_Texture* ImageFunc::LoadSprites(const char* filename,bool alpha,int r, int g, int b)
{
    SDL_Surface* old_image=NULL;
    SDL_Texture* new_image=NULL;
    old_image=SDL_LoadBMP(filename);

    if(!old_image)
        printf("image loadinf failure: image func: SDL_LoadBMP \n");

    if(alpha)
        SDL_SetColorKey( old_image, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB( old_image->format,r, g,b ) );

    new_image=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Global::renderer,old_image);

    if(!new_image)
        printf("image loading failure: image_func\n");

    SDL_FreeSurface(old_image);
    return new_image;
}
```

(ImageFunc is a namespace)

So this will not work:

```
void Button::Init()
{
}

Button::Button()
{
    position_.x = 0;
    position_.y = 0;
    position_.w = 200;
    position_.h = 100;
    image_ = ImageFunc::LoadSprites("Images/ButtonPlay.bmp");
}
```

But if I put the loading LoadSprite in the Init method it'll work.

The constructor and init method are called at exactly the same time:

```
buttonPlay_ = Button();
buttonPlay_.Init();
```

It's worth noting that it's in a constructor and buttonPlay_ is an attribute.

Any idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy a class that contains a raw pointer that easily. The texture is a resource of your class, you have to manage it (and its lifetime).

```
buttonPlay_ = Button();
```

- creates temporary `Button`, copies that into `buttonPlay_` and the temporary `Button` is destructed, `SDL_DestroyTexture(image_)` is called. That results in dangling `image_` pointer in `buttonPlay_`. It points to texture that was destroyed.

If you can, the simplest thing to do is to forbid copying of `Button` and initialize `buttonPlay_` just once and don't reassign it. But if you need `Button` to be copyable, you should be able make a deep copy with [`SDL_RenderCopy`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy) or [`SDL_RenderCopyEx`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx). I recommend the first option, though.

**Edit:**

If `buttonPlay_ = Button();` is in a constructor, it should be initialized in member initializer list, avoiding copy-constructor call:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass() :
buttonPlay_()
{
}
```

Your constructor would default-construct `buttonPlay_` anyway, if you didn't declare it.

Comment: My logic was that if I explicitly called the constructor again, the destructor would be called and then the object would be constructed again (the plan was to overload the constructor). It's worth noting that it still doesn't work if I put the image loading in an overloaded constructor only (so that it's not called by the default constructor).

Comment: With `buttonPlay_ = Button();`, the destructor is called after the assignment, there's no way to copy-construct with already destructed object... However, what I posted should work fine.

Comment: Try it out, don't forget to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Yeah, it was my first post, was trying to figure out how to accept the answer.